# Huawei Mapkit Dependency Error: Could not find com.huawei.hms:maps:6.0.0.301. Required by: project :app

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I need to add Huawei Mapkit on my project in Kotlin. But when i add Dependency and pressed to sync button i am getting this error. I was implement all dependency and files but i am still getting this error. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-mapkit-demo/tree/master/kotlin) is huawei map kit  kotlin demo. You could try to run this demo directly.

And check if added the 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' in build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: I checked my gradle files but its same already. You can see my repo on https://github.com/alicimsamil/MapsDirectionsExamples/tree/error.

Comment: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-mapkit-demo/tree/master/kotlin  Did you encounter similar errors when you tried the demo code?

Comment: I found solution. Mapkit dependency cant runing on classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0" i changed to classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4" and its works.

Comment: Great! feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)